# Ruby read Samba share

Tags: ruby, samba, smb

I'm looking for a way to read from a samba share. I want to use it like the `Dir` class, for example open and read of directories. Is this possible in Ruby?

Comment: Dear mibo, http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=samba+ruby+gem , Love, Google

Comment: yes I had found. But since
it is not developed, I
thought maybe there is a
current gem.

Comment: Sambala work with ftools but ftools is deprecated since ruby 1.9.2. So its seems to be not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

The Sambala gem should work for you if your host OS is a Posix (UNIX-like) system (not sure about Windows...):

```
gem install sambala
```

This gem will work as long as your host OS has a working smbclient executable somewhere in your $PATH.  As long as you're using Mac OS X, Linux, or some other UNIX variant, you should be able to run the following command from the terminal to see if you've got smbclient somewhere in your path:

```
which smbclient
```

If you don't get a result, do a google search on how to obtain smbclient for your current host OS.  If you're on Mac OS X, you can simply [install MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and then run the following command from the terminal to get smbclient installed:

```
sudo port install samba3
```

Comment: Sambala work with ftools but ftools is deprecated since ruby 1.9.2. So its seems to be not working for me.

Comment: It's not terribly complicated to replace ftools with fileutils in most cases, so you could consider forking sambala at https://github.com/lp/sambala, and update it for 1.9.2

Comment: Yea, ftools isn't required in sambala, but in the abundance gem, which is required from sambala. It was not so easy to find the include of ftools because on github code ftools will not be used. But my local gem abundance use one ftool function. But it doesn't work. i can't connect to my samba share. i think i will use ssh etc to get the network shares. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try to check my gem, i've started it cause i've same issues with sambala

https://github.com/reivilo/rsmbclient

Comment: this is an incomplete gem a full year later. It does not provide the basic functionality requested in question.

Answer (score 0):

The Sambala gem will work for 1.8.x Ruby implementations on a Posix (UNIX-like) system

```
gem install sambala
```

For 1.9.x Ruby on Posix use GLSIGNAL's fork.

```
git clone https://github.com/glsignal/sambala.git
cd sambala
gem build samabala
gem install ./sambala.gem
```

Note: GLSignal's gem uses a github source of abundance that is patched to run on 1.9.x

As stated by lottscarson, these gems will work as long as your host OS has a working smbclient executable somewhere in your $PATH.  As long as you're using Mac OS X, Linux, or some other Posix variant, you should be able to run the following command from the terminal to see if you've got smbclient somewhere in your path:

```
which smbclient
```

If you don't get a result, do a google search on how to obtain smbclient for your current host OS. (examples)

```
(RHEL/CENTOS/etc) yum install samba

(ubuntu/debian) sudo apt-get install samba smbfs

(osx) brew install samba
```

---

As an alternative to a wrapper for smbclient you could use a C extension ruby gem called 'net-smb'. This requires native compilation, and is not written pure ruby.

```
gem install net-smb
```

This requires a few things as well.

```
Ruby 1.9.3+
Samba 3.5+ (libsmbclient)
C compiler
```

Installation examples

```
sudo apt-get install libsmbclient libsmbclient-dev
```

Comment: GLSignals version of abundance is 1.3.6, the last version by pl (the orginal author) is 1.3.5

Comment: GLSignals version of sambala is 0.9.9 and pl's is 0.9.8

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby_SMB](https://github.com/rapid7/ruby_smb) is a native Ruby implementation of the SMB Protocol Family.

From the [README](https://github.com/rapid7/ruby_smb#connecting-to-a-tree):

```
  sock = TCPSocket.new address, 445
  dispatcher = RubySMB::Dispatcher::Socket.new(sock)

  client = RubySMB::Client.new(dispatcher, username: 'msfadmin', password: 'msfadmin')
  client.negotiate
  client.authenticate

  begin
    tree = client.tree_connect('TEST_SHARE')
    puts "Connected to #{path} successfully!"
  rescue StandardError => e
    puts "Failed to connect to #{path}: #{e.message}"
  end

  files = tree.list(directory: 'subdir1')

  files.each do |file|
    create_time = file.create_time.to_datetime.to_s
    access_time = file.last_access.to_datetime.to_s
    change_time = file.last_change.to_datetime.to_s
    file_name   = file.file_name.encode("UTF-8")

    puts "FILE: #{file_name}\n\tSIZE(BYTES):#{file.end_of_file}\n\tSIZE_ON_DISK(BYTES):#{file.allocation_size}\n\tCREATED:#{create_time}\n\tACCESSED:#{access_time}\n\tCHANGED:#{change_time}\n\n"
  end
```