# Accessing folders of remote host for windows system

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a Ruby script which accesses folders on a remote host. I am able to access the folders on Linux systems using NET::SSH.

How can I access folders of a remote Windows system?

Comment: You should consider sharing some of the code you've already tried

Comment: Depends on how the "remote Windows system" is configured.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows directory are shared through SMB protocol, you can take a look at different SMB gems:
[Ruby read Samba share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733648/ruby-read-samba-share)